# plone.app.theming RHEL issues

Tags: plone, redhat, diazo

I am trying to get plone.app.theming working on a RHEL 5 box.  Buildout installed this package and its dependencies without issue.  I can also install the product (Diazo theme support) on a Plone site and access the Diazo theming control panel.  However, I am getting an error when running in debug mode about XSLT tranforms failing.  After much research, I believe the issue lies with the fact that two packages in RHEL, libxml2 and libxslt2, are older than what I need to get this working.

Is there a work around to get this up and running in my case?  I am not a Linux admin, so any thoughts or suggestions would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570183/unable-to-use-diazo-plone-app-theming-on-centos

Answer (score 1):

Either use the Unified Installer for 4.1, which sets this up for you, or add the following to your buildout, which will build lxml, libxml2 and libxslt without touching your system's libraries:

```
parts += lxml pylxml

[lxml]
recipe = z3c.recipe.staticlxml
egg = lxml
libxml2-url = ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.7.8.tar.gz
libxslt-url = ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz
static-build = true

[pylxml]
recipe=zc.recipe.egg
interpreter=pylxml
eggs=
    lxml
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.  This was the direction I was headed.  However, when I run this in buildout, my instances start, but I can not access Zope or Plone afterwards.  Starting in debug mode shows the following error:

ImportError: /usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/lxml-2.2.8-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/lxml/etree.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a CentOs 5.x
There isn't a solution. I pass an entire weekend fighting with lxml, zlib & co.

The problem is a reference to zlib in lxml caused by a wrong position of this library in a 64bit system. Googling I found that it's a widely problem, not only for the plonistas.

The only way, for me, it's use CentOs 6.
Vito