# How to convert XML into HTML using XSLT 2 transformation from Python3?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml, xslt-2.0

I use [XSLT 2.0 file](http://view-source:https://www.iso.org/schema/isosts/resources/isosts2html_standalone.xsl) for converting ISOSTS XML document into HTML.

My code:

```
from lxml.etree import parse, XSLT

xslt = parse('/path/to/isosts2html_standalone.xsl')

# fixme: it works, but standard xsl fails!
# xslt = XML('''\
# <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
#     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
#     <xsl:template match="/">
#         <foo><xsl:value-of select="/a/b/text()" /></foo>
#     </xsl:template>
# </xsl:stylesheet>''')

self._transformer = XSLT(xslt)  # <- FAILS !!!

dom = parse(file)
new_dom = self._transformer(dom)
return tostring(new_dom, pretty_print=True)
```

I have next error:

> File "src/lxml/xslt.pxi", line 406, in lxml.etree.XSLT.**init** (src/lxml/etree.c:185192)
>   lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Start of literal

Or next error using `isosts2html.xsl` [from archive](https://www.iso.org/schema/isosts/resources/isosts2html.zip):

> File "src/lxml/xslt.pxi", line 406, in lxml.etree.XSLT.**init** (src/lxml/etree.c:185192)
>   lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Invalid expression

Does lxml support XSLT 2.0 and how to solve problem?

Comment: lxml uses libxslt which is an XSLT 1.0 processor so you can't use it to run XSLT 2.0 stylesheets (using any features that are not available in XSLT and XPath 1.0). So you would need to run XSLT 2 outside of Python by using Saxon 9 (available for the Java and .NET platform) or Saxon-C and have your Python program call Saxon.

Comment: @Martin Honnen, thanks! I think it is good solution for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plone - XSLTApplyError: xsltValueOf: text copy failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644695/plone-xsltapplyerror-xsltvalueof-text-copy-failed)

Comment: please include the error information provided by lxml.etree.XMLSchema('').error_log See: lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#errors-and-messages

Comment: @dank8 Question was asked about 5 years ago, I have no logs now. There were no problems with XSLT 1, but with XSLT 2 only. In that project I used Saxon and it worked well.